# How to create a World in Box2D without leaving Unresolved Externals

Tags: c++, visual-studio, box2d, sfml

I've been looking into 2D physics engines and Box2D came up. I've been reading into it and trying to set things up but have had issues.

1. Create the build with premake5
2. Open up a new Visual Studio 2019 project
3. Set the Additional Include Directory to the Box2D header folder
4. Set the Additional Library Directories (under linker) to the folder that contains the lib file (Box2D.lib)
5. Set the Additional Dependencies to Box2D.lib

With this all done I seem to be able to call and create Box2d Variables and functions without issue. But while I was trying to set up a world it began to cause errors.

The Errors

```
LNK1120 2 unresolved externals          

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall b2World::b2World(struct b2Vec2 const &)" (??0b2World@@QAE@ABUb2Vec2@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Game::run(void)" (?run@Game@@QAEXXZ)                

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall b2World::~b2World(void)" (??1b2World@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Game::run(void)" (?run@Game@@QAEXXZ)
```

The project I'm setting up is an attempt to use SFML with Box2d. Running the testbed in the generated folder works but I'm trying to figure out how to port the engine into other projects if needed. The solution works as expected. But as soon as the World Variable is created it creates errors.

But creating and setting the b2Vec2 and b2BodyDef variables cause no issues. I'm not quite sure what the cause could be, I've looked through the various guides online, checked the paths were correct and regenerated the library file.

I suspect that the issue is that Box2D was configured to build in x64 and my project is building in x86. I was wondering if anyone would know a way to either run Box2D in x86 or something of the sort.

The Code

```
void Game::run()
{
    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;
    sf::Time timePerFrame = sf::seconds(1.f / 60.f); // 60 fps
    b2Vec2 gravity(0.0f, -10.0f);


    b2World myWorld = b2World(gravity); //The errors are cause by this line.

    // Define the ground body.
    b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
    groundBodyDef.position.Set(0.0f, -10.0f);



    while (m_window.isOpen())
    {
        processEvents(); // as many as possible
        timeSinceLastUpdate += clock.restart();
        while (timeSinceLastUpdate > timePerFrame)
        {
            timeSinceLastUpdate -= timePerFrame;
            processEvents(); // at least 60 fps
            update(timePerFrame); //60 fps
        }
        render(); // as many as possible
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/5910058

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

The problem was caused by the library file being generated by the test bed being for a x64 system. Regenerating a library file in a Win(32) mode generated the correct library file which resolved the